# ODBC Firebird Sql Query - Syntax

Tags: sql, odbc, firebird

Trying to get an slightly more complex sql statement structured but can't seem to get the syntax right. Trying to select counts, of various columns, in two different tables.

```
SELECT 
     SUM(ColumninTable1), 
     SUM(Column2inTable1), 
     COUNT(DISTINCT(Column3inTable1)) 
FROM TABLE1
```

This works, however I can't for the life of me figure out how to add in a COUNT(DISTINCT(Column1inTable2) FROM TABLE2 with what syntax.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve here.

Comment: Just trying to run a report. However I wish to  do one more count(distinct) from another table. SELECT 
    SUM(IMG_RAM), 
    SUM(IMG_CORE_COUNT), 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(IMG_NAME)) 
    FROM IMAGES

Comment: Everything is possible, but you usually only query two tables if they have a logical relationship, and that relationship might (need to) influence the result of the count.

Comment: Ok. They have no logical relationship, for this report, so two queries it is...

Comment: It is still possible with a single query.

Comment: That was my original question

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions you can take:

**Disjunct `FULL OUTER JOIN`**

```
SELECT 
    SUM(MYTABLE.ID) as theSum,
    COUNT(DISTINCT MYTABLE.SOMEVALUE) as theCount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT MYOTHERTABLE.SOMEOTHERVALUE) as theOtherCount
FROM MYTABLE
FULL OUTER JOIN MYOTHERTABLE ON 1=0
```

**`UNION` two queries and leave the column for the other table null**

```
SELECT 
    MAX(theSum) as theSum, 
    MAX(theCount) as theCount, 
    MAX(theOtherCount) AS theOtherCount
FROM (
    SELECT
        SUM(ID) as theSum,
        COUNT(DISTINCT SOMEVALUE) as theCount,
        NULL as theOtherCount
    FROM MYTABLE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        NULL,
        NULL,
        COUNT(DISTINCT SOMEOTHERVALUE)
    FROM MYOTHERTABLE
)
```

**Query 'with a query per column' against a single record table (eg `RDB$DATABASE`)**

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(ID) FROM MYTABLE) as theSum,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SOMEVALUE) FROM MYTABLE) as theCount,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SOMEOTHERVALUE) FROM MYOTHERTABLE) as theOtherCount
FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

**CTE per table + cross join**

```
WITH query1 AS (
    SELECT
        SUM(ID) as theSum,
        COUNT(DISTINCT SOMEVALUE) as theCount
    FROM MYTABLE
),
query2 AS (
    SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT SOMEOTHERVALUE) as theOtherCount
    FROM MYOTHERTABLE
)
SELECT 
    query1.theSum,
    query1.theCount,
    query2.theOtherCount
FROM query1
CROSS JOIN query2
```

There are probably some more solutions. You might want to ask yourself if it is worth the effort of coming up with a (convoluted, hard to understand) single query to get this data were two queries are sufficient, easier to understand and in the case of large datasets: two separate queries might be faster.

Comment: Thank you. As you said, 2 queries seems to be the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

In this case all "count" would return the same value.

Try to do the same using sub queries:

```
  Select 
   (Select count (*) from Table1), 
   (Select count (*) from table2) 
  from Table3
```